# Fill SVG element with a repeating linear gradient color

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I have an SVG element - a rectangle.

Now, to color this element, I use `fill` attribute that works with any color.

Now, I am trying to give it a stripes color by using this property

```
fill: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #cc2229, #ffffff 4px, #cc2229 2px, #ffffff 8px);
```

This works for normal DOM elements when assigned to `background` attribute.

But, IT DOESN'T WORK WITH SVG ELEMENT.

How can i achieve that?

[image] - this is how i am trying my SVG element to look like (I am using d3.js)

Comment: This is not how SVG gradients work. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients

Comment: For interest's sake, it's worth mentioning that there are plans for SVG2 to allow you to use CSS image values (including CSS gradient functions) as SVG fill values.  But the details haven't been decided, and no one supports it yet.  You have to use SVG gradients for SVG elements, as explained in the tutorial Lars linked to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Lars and AmeliaBR

Here is the code:

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Gradient-1"x1="3%" y1="4%" x2="6%" y2="6%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color= "red" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color= "white" />
      </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="repeat"xlink:href="#Gradient-1"spreadMethod="repeat" />
  </defs>
  <rect x="30" y="10"
        width="200" height="100"
        fill= "url(#repeat)"
        stroke="red"
        stroke-width="2px" />
</svg>
```

Comment: There's no reason to use 2 gradients just move the spreadMethod to the first one and use it directly.

Answer (score 27):

Much better solution:

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern"
             width="8" height="10"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
             patternTransform="rotate(45 50 50)">
      <line stroke="#a6a6a6" stroke-width="7px" y2="10"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
    <rect x="5" y="5"
          width="1000" height="25"
          fill= "url(#pattern)"
          opacity="0.4"
          stroke="#a6a6a6"
          stroke-width="2px" />
 </svg>
```

Comment: two ways to solve this view you want, my opinion is the pattern way, cause of the consistentivity strips creat on the shape you will use on.

linear gradient will work but if you will use it on sepral chart it will have diffrent behavior.

hope it will help with some direction to use the **Pattern** way

pattern - http://jsfiddle.net/hodca/yduKG/254/

lineargradient -  as above included above - http://jsfiddle.net/hodca/mcab43nd/87/


all the best!