# How to apply "background: repeating-linear-gradient" style for rect using d3.js

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

I'm having trouble to replicate *repeating-linear-gradient* styling for rect using d3.

**eg:**
I have the following *div* style:

```
.colorbarssegment{ 
     background: repeating-linear-gradient( to right, 
                        #c0c0c0, #c0c0c0 4px, 
                        #c0c000 4px, #c0c000 8px, 
                        #00c0c0 8px, #00c0c0 12px, 
                        #00c000 12px, #00c000 16px, 
                        #c000c0 16px, #c000c0 20px, 
                        #c00000 20px, #c00000 24px, 
                        #0000c0 24px, #0000c0 28px);
 }
```

when I use the class in div like:

```
<div class="colorbarssegment" style="width: 200px; height: 20px;"></div>
```

it looks like : 
[image]

How can I apply the same style for *rect* in *d3.js*?

Comment: Sorry sir, it's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill SVG element with a repeating linear gradient color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511153/fill-svg-element-with-a-repeating-linear-gradient-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxrw6kvt/)! I think this solution will do what you require.

```
<svg width="500" height="240" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient2" x1="16%" x2="1%" y1="50%" y2="50%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#c0c0c0"/>
        <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#c0c000"/>
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#c0c000"/>
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#c000c0"/>
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#c00000"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0000c0"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="repeat"xlink:href="#Gradient2"spreadMethod="repeat" />
      <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
        #rect1 { fill: url(#repeat); }
        .stop1 { stop-color: #c0c0c0; }
        .stop2 { stop-color: #c0c000; }
        .stop3 { stop-color: #c0c000; }
        .stop4 { stop-color: #c000c0; }
        .stop5 { stop-color: #c00000; }
        .stop6 { stop-color: #0000c0; }
      ]]></style>
  </defs>

  <rect id="rect1" x="10" y="10" rx="15" ry="15" width="120" height="30"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to define a pattern in your SVG as described on this page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns

I have created a fiddle that has a pattern similar to what you need:
http://jsfiddle.net/11k570ud/

After that, you give the `rect` the attribute:

```
fill="url(#yourPatternID)"
```

You can either include this in the svg code, or add it with D3.js. An explanation of how to do that can be found [here](http://dev.mikamai.com/post/86583300944/using-svg-gradient-masks-with-d3js) (this post uses Gradients, but Patterns work in a very similar way).

Comment: I was just going to link to [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns)

Comment: You're right, for a repeating Gradient you need a Pattern